# MatAutocompleteTrigger optionSelections Observable stops firing

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a problem with the Angular Material Auto Complete. Once the autocomplete suggestions are empty, the autocompleteTrigger optionSelection Observable does not trigger any more.

I made a subscription to optionSelections Observable and once the filter function gets back an empty array it will never emit a new value.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/autocomplete-force-selection-4cyhez?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: seems working demo in stackblitz can you tell us more about your issue

Comment: For me it's not working. If i typ for example David and clear the input and select Mary the function does not fire and the coutnter does not increase.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.